# Sub query on a condition

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT a.product_title, b.product_title FROM products a, products b 
WHERE b.color_id = a.color_id 
AND b.price_id = a.price_id 
AND b.size_id = a.size_id 
AND a.id = 1
AND ??? (SELECT * FROM products LIMIT ???);
```

I'm trying to perform a sub query if the results of the first query is less than 10, how would I do this? Is it possible to count the rows the query gets out in the same query without performing another query?

Also is it possible to set the LIMIT to be what is required, ie. the first query gets 6 rows, I then need the limit to be 4 - to make up 10 all together.

Comment: i think you can do something if you find something that permit to differ answer from the first and second query with that : 
    SELECT a.product_title, b.product_title FROM products a, products b 
WHERE b.color_id = a.color_id 
AND b.price_id = a.price_id 
AND b.size_id = a.size_id 
AND a.id = 1
OR a.id = 1 AND b.id in (SELECT * FROM products) GROUP BY ???? LIMIT 10;

Answer (score 0):

I Really don't understand your question well,

anyway you can use **variables** ,

Example:

```
Set ACount = (select count(a.id) from products a where ...=...);
SELECT a.product_title, b.product_title FROM products a, products b 
WHERE b.color_id = a.color_id 
AND b.price_id = a.price_id 
AND b.size_id = a.size_id 
AND a.id = 1
AND if(@ACount<10, "Your where statement here",0);
```

Comment: Proper DDLs, a data set, a result set would clarify this problem (and all problems) immensely

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using "UNION".

If you don't care about performance and just want to save one query, you can always UNION an second query and get the top 10 rows from the combined result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.product_title, b.product_title , 0 as Rank
FROM products a, products b 
WHERE b.color_id = a.color_id 
AND b.price_id = a.price_id 
AND b.size_id = a.size_id 
AND a.id = 1
LIMIT 10
UNION 
SELECT product_title, '', Rank
FROM products  
WHERE (your condition)
LIMIT 20
) E 
ORDER BY Rank
LIMIT 10
```

Since the extra results from the second query will have higher rank, if you already have 10 records in the first query, there will be dropped by the limit.

Since Union will remove duplicates so you need add enough results to make sure you get at least 10.

The above code is to show you the concept and you need adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks, how many select queries is this? Would it be better performance wise to do one query, then in php check the count, if less than 10, do another query?

Comment: Depends on how often you need the second query and how fast is the second query. This kind of queries are usually done to build a view or function so the front-end (php) does not need to worry about those thing.

Comment: From front-end, it's one query. And you should don't it if rarely need to the second query and your second query is slow.